# Split two $_GET variables into path

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule that works something like:

```
www.sitename.com/products.php?p=product&c=category
```

should become

```
www.sitename.com/product/category
```

I have tried the following, but my RegEx knowledge is far from ideal and the following does not work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ products.php?p=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's located directly in the root of the website, no other rules.

Comment: Need more info. What are the URLs you want to handle with this rule? Are there more rules etc?

Comment: I only want products.php with its two variables redirect to site.com/var1/var2 . I want all the other paths to work and be the same. The only other rule I'm going to add will be `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1\.php [QSA,L]` so it converts from the php extension to html for the simple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?p=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's partially working, but I guess it has to do more with me than with your code. I'm testing this on my localhost and everything is in a folder. So I'm accessing the site through http://localhost/sitename/ . I've changed the RewriteBase to be /sitename/ and the first part (the products.php one) works fine, unfortunately the php to html filename conversion returns "Not Found". Any idea of what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: For that condition needs to be: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitename/$1\.php -f [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `(.*)` with `([^/]+)`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, but unfortunately now any path like www.site.com/fund/aaa/bula/a will go to products.php ...

Comment: Yea, I like to make the first uri segment in all my routes static for that very reason.

Comment: And how could I make the segment static in order to avoid that behavior? Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ products.php?p=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]`, 
`RewriteRule ^funds/(.*)/(.*)$ fund.php?p=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]` and so on

Comment: That solution works fine too, thanks! I did pick anubhava's response though as it works exactly as wanted, without the leading segment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule www.sitename.com/(.*)/(.*) $products.php?p=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You can test your rewrite rules in [this site](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not work. The resource site looks good too, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either. Maybe I've missed something.